# Cinema 4D Scaling to Real Life modelling

Tags: 3d, cinema-4d

I have been using this application for abit but still really new! I have watched loads of tutorials but nothing has actually told me how to size models to real life!

In Cinema 4D you have a a pre-made figure in the Cube dialog with a height of 600.312 cm, this would make the figure 19 foot tall!

So my question is basically, how is 3D models scaled to real life?

Is this figure just incorrectly scaled?

My height is 182cm's, in the 3D world of cinema 4D, would i be the same height?

I have googled this question but nothing really explains it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're able to switch between the metric system and "non metric system".
   Go to preferences - unit and change to the desired one.
2. If you use the figure from Cinema 4D you have a size reference (adjust the size in the attributmanager) which will be the same as in reality.